# Javascipt function are not coming in VF page html

Tags: visualforce

I am working on page and calling a Javascript function on click. I am getting an reference error "Function in not defined". I debug the issue and , when I see the page HTML with firebug I don't find any of the javascript function I defined . How come script is not loaded in page. I simply put it within  tag , but functions are not there.. please advise. Thanks

Comment: Can you please show the code which is not working?

Comment: I have resolved it but didn't understand the issue. I have 3 js function in script tag and calling them "onclick" of 3 seperate button . There was "uncaught Syntax" with one of the function but JS was not identifying any of the function and throwing function not defined error for all of them . Why this ?

Comment: Were the other 2 functions working which did not have JS syntax problem ?

Comment: Nope. I was getting function not defined for all java script function . I think , it should not happen right. I have been calling all function explicitly and there was no re rendering as well.

Comment: Seems strange, could you share the code. Normally the other functions should run properly if they are not related (calling one another )

Comment: sounds like the error was in blocks of code prior to the functions that blocked the whole script from loading.